# How to force transaction commit in Spring Boot test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How can I force a transaction commit in Spring Boot (with Spring Data) **while running a method** and **not** after the method ?

I've read here that it should be possible with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` in another class but doesn't work for me.

Any hints? I'm using Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CommitTest {

    @Autowired
    TestRepo repo;

    @Transactional
    @Commit
    @Test
    public void testCommit() {
        repo.createPerson();
        System.out.println("I want a commit here!");
        // ...
        System.out.println("Something after the commit...");
    }
}

@Repository
public class TestRepo {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepo;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createPerson() {
        personRepo.save(new Person("test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: By not making your test transactional, then your software behaves as it does in your environment. If your transactions are completely not working then you are probably doing something wrong in your configuration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An approach would be to inject the `TransactionTemplate` in the test class, remove the `@Transactional` and `@Commit` and modify the test method to something like:

```
...
public class CommitTest {

    @Autowired
    TestRepo repo;

    @Autowired
    TransactionTemplate txTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testCommit() {
        txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

          @Override
          protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            repo.createPerson();
            // ...
          }
        });

        // ...
        System.out.println("Something after the commit...");
    }
```

Or

```
new TransactionCallback<Person>() {

    @Override
    public Person doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
      // ...
      return person
    }

    // ...
});
```

instead of the `TransactionCallbackWithoutResult` callback impl if you plan to add assertions to the person object that was just persisted.

Answer (score 29):

Use the helper class `org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestTransaction` (since Spring 4.1).

Tests are rolled back per default. To really commit one needs to do

```java
// do something before the commit 

TestTransaction.flagForCommit(); // need this, otherwise the next line does a rollback
TestTransaction.end();
TestTransaction.start();

// do something in new transaction
```

Comment: While this works in non-boot env, in Spring Boot I had hard time making this work, since one needs to enable `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` somehow, and that one plays badly with Spring boot annotations.

Comment: Strange. I exactly use this in SpringBootTests in combination with  `@SpringBootTest` and `@Transactional`

Answer (score 2):

Solutions with lambdas.

```
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

@Autowired
TestRepo repo;

@Autowired
TransactionTemplate txTemplate;

private <T> T doInTransaction(Supplier<T> operation) {
    return txTemplate.execute(status -> operation.get());
}

private void doInTransaction(Runnable operation) {
    txTemplate.execute(status -> {
        operation.run();
        return null;
    });
}
```

use as

```
Person saved = doInTransaction(() -> repo.save(buildPerson(...)));

doInTransaction(() -> repo.delete(person));
```

Comment: Please add your imports on top such that it is clear which classes you use. Also you can remove TestRpeo it's not used in your code.