# How to prevent rollback operation for each test in TestNg + Spring + H2 database?

Tags: spring-boot, testng

I am using spring boot integration test with h2 database and testNg for integration tests.
And my spring boot application uses spring data jpa.
For each test, i am unable to see data saved by the previous tests.
Below is my Integration test class:-

```
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = APP.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    @Rollback(false)
    private void m1() {
        // save data.        
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    @Rollback(false)
    private void m2() {        

        // retrieve saved data. (Failed)
    }

 }
```

I am using TestRestTemplate to test test PUT and POST Rest endpoints.

Comment: What does  // save data.      do?

Comment: It calls the POST Rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `@SpringBootTest` annotation, which means you will start an entire spring-boot application. `@Commit` and `@Rollback` are to use with `@DataJpaTest`, or something similar, when your test is `@Transactional` to have a good control.

Here is what I think:

- Either there is a problem with TestNG and Spring, in which case, there is not much I can do
- Or your code is in fault. Have you tried using some breakpoints to see if your code goes through all your layers.

Could you show more of your code ? The test code, the controller, the service and data layer. And of course, your configuration classes, that would be great in order to help

---

You have to use the annotation `@Commit` and not `@Rollback`

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = APP.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Test
    @Commit
    private void m1() {
    }
 }
```

Alternatively, you could use `TransactionTemplate` for a more grained control. See this: [How to force transaction commit in Spring Boot test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079793/how-to-force-transaction-commit-in-spring-boot-test).

Comment: I tried both approaches. Still it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your repository calls within a transaction.

```
    final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<R>() {
        @Override
        public R doInTransaction(final TransactionStatus status) {
            myRepository.save(myEntity);
        }
    });
```